# Bind an int array to a listview

Tags: android, listview

I set up a listview with an arrayadapter in android studio. Pretty basic stuff. I can save and delete listview ids, and I set up an onItemClickListener to retrieve the id string. 
But what I want to do now is bind/save an int array to every item. For example:

pos 0, id "Jesus" -> int values: "10, 13, 256, 0, 57, ..."
pos 1, id "Moses" -> int values: "80, 70, 60, ..."
and so on.

The int array does not have to be displayed in the listview. All I want to do is bind it to the listview item. And then, by clicking on an item, retrieve the int array.
Does anybody has a tipp on how to implement this?

this is my code so far (as I said pretty basic):

```
    etPresetName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPresetName);

    lvPresets = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvPresets);
    lvPresets.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            String str = lvPresets.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
            etPresetName.setText(str);
        }
    });



    alPresets = new ArrayList<String>();
    PresetsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Presets.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            alPresets);
    lvPresets.setAdapter(PresetClassAdapter);
```

Comment: Just make a class to wrap all things together and use new class in the `ListView`

Comment: show your adapter class

Comment: thanks for the answers, but I'm afraid I miss the basic knowledge to understand that. I dont know how to "just make a class to wrap all things together".
I try to add the stuff I already got in the question above.

Comment: refer this demo https://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

Comment: thanks, but I have trouble extracting the things I need out of this tutorial. Reason is, it does not explain the code step by step, so I have trouble sorting out everything I don't need like XML stuff and customized list adapter. All I need is to store an int array behind the listitem id.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom class to hold your data

```
class MyClass{
    String title;
    int[] array; 
}
```

Create Custom ArrayAdapter with your data class.

```
public class MyClassAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyClass> {

    public MyClassAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, 
        ArrayList<MyClass> items) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
        .........
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
         .........
         Item item = item.get(position)
    }
}
```

Now on your onClick listener you can get int array from list with position.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but although I understand roughly how this solves my problem, I'm not skilled enough to fully implement this into my code. I edited my post on top to show my code so far. How can I implement your code example into this?